# CUDA, is there an atomicRead?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am working on a CUDA program where all blocks and threads need to determine the minimum step size for an iterative problem dynamically.  I want the first thread in the block to be responsible for reading in the global dz value to shared memory so the rest of the threads can do a reduction on it.  Meanwhile other threads in other blocks may be writing to it.  Is there simply an atomicRead option in CUDA or something equivalent.  I guess I could do an atomic add with zero or something.  Or is this even necessary?

```
template<typename IndexOfRefractionFunct>
    __global__ void _step_size_kernel(IndexOfRefractionFunct n, double* dz, double z, double cell_size)
    {
        int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        if(idx >= cells * cells)
            return;

        int idy = idx / cells;
        idx %= cells;

        double x = cell_size * idx;
        double y = cell_size * idy;

        __shared__ double current_dz;
        if(threadIdx.x == 0)
            current_dz = atomicRead(dz);

        ...

        atomicMin(dz, calculated_min);
    }
```

Also I just realized that cuda does not seem to support atomics on doubles.  Any way around this?

Comment: No, CUDA has no equivalent of atomic loads, regrettably. You can workaround that with an `atomicAdd(0)` as you mention, or adding a barrier before a regular load. Although the semantics will indeed not be those of an atomic load, the result is, as far as I know, the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there simply an atomicRead option in CUDA or something equivalent.

The idea of an `atomic` operation is that it allows for combining multiple operations without the possibility of intervening operations from other threads.  The canonical use is for a read-modify-write.  All 3 steps of the RMW operation can be performed atomically, with respect to a given location in memory, without the possibility of intervening activity from other threads.

Therefore the concept of an atomic *read* (only, by itself) doesn't really have meaning in this context.  It is only one operation.  In CUDA, all properly aligned reads of basic types (`int`, `float`, `double`, etc.) occur atomically, i.e. all in one operation, without the possibility of other operations affecting that read, or parts of that read.

Based on what you have shown, it seems that the correctness of your use-case should be satisfied without any special behavior on the read operation.   If you simply wanted to ensure that the `current_dz` value gets populated from the global value, before any threads have a chance to modify it,  at the block level, this can be sorted out simply with `__syncthreads()`:

```
    __shared__ double current_dz;
    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
        current_dz = dz;
    __syncthreads(); // no threads can proceed beyond this point until
                     // thread 0 has read the value of dz

    ...

    atomicMin(dz, calculated_min);
```

If you need to make sure this behavior is enforced grid-wide, then my suggestion would be to have an initial value of dz that threads *don't* write to, followed by the atomicMin operation being done on another location (ie. separate the write/output from the read/input at the kernel level).

But, again, I'm not suggesting this is necessary for your use-case.  If you simply want to pick up the *current* `dz` value, you can do this with an ordinary read.  You will get a "coherent" value. At the grid level, some number of `atomicMin` operations may have occurred before that read, and some may have occurred after that read, but none of them will *corrupt* the read, leading you to read a bogus value.  The value you read will be either the initial value that was there, or some value that was properly deposited by an `atomicMin` operation (based on the code you have shown).

> Also I just realized that cuda does not seem to support atomics on doubles. Any way around this?

CUDA has support for a limited set of atomic operations on 64-bit quantities. In particular, there is a 64-bit `atomicCAS` operation.  The [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) demonstrates how to use this in a custom function to achieve an arbitrary 64 bit atomic operation (e.g. 64-bit `atomicMin` on a `double` quantity).  The example in the programming guide describes how to do a `double` `atomicAdd` operation.  Here are examples of `atomicMin` and `atomicMax` operating on `double`:

```
__device__ double atomicMax(double* address, double val)
{
  unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =(unsigned long long int*)address;
  unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;

  while(val > __longlong_as_double(old) ) {
    assumed = old;
    old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val));
  }

  return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
__device__ double atomicMin(double* address, double val)
{
  unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =(unsigned long long int*)address;
  unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;

  while(val < __longlong_as_double(old) ) {
    assumed = old;
    old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed, __double_as_longlong(val));
  }

  return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
```

As a good programming practice, atomics should be used sparingly, although Kepler global 32-bit atomics are pretty fast.   But when using these types of custom 64-bit atomics, the advice is especially applicable; they will be noticeably slower than ordinary reads and writes.

Comment: Is there a chapter in the reference that mentions the fact that "in CUDA all properly aligned reads of basic types" are atomic by default? Is this also true for non-native types like 64 bit integers?

Comment: There isn't really.  There is one for PTX, it is contained in the PTX guide, under the memory section (which is rather difficult to parse) and covers reads up to 64-bits.  There is also a [paper](https://github.com/NVlabs/ptxmemorymodel/blob/master/PTXMemoryModelASPLOS2019.pdf) and you can read the section of the PTX guide [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#memory-consistency-model).  I'm not sure why you are referring to a 64-bit integer as a "non-native type".  I don't know what that means.

Comment: Well what I read about integer processing is that types up to 32 bit are supported by hardware while integer > 32 bit would consist of multiple operations of smaller bit width (making 64 bit integer operations much slower than 32 bit integer operations on current CUDA devices). So one could assume the 64 bit ints maybe are different regarding reads.

Comment: It's true that the GPU is basically a 32-bit machine that has enough "extensions" of various types to make it suitable for 64-bit code.  If it were me, I would not translate that statement into "64-bit integer is a non-native type."  That's just my viewpoint, I guess.