# Confused about the lack of atomicRead in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to understand why there is no `atomicRead` in CUDA. According to [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) article, if two different threads ever attempt to access the same memory, that is undefined behavior. Yet, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36102297/1031791) SO answer, you can actually use reads and writes to the same memory, it is just that they aren't guaranteed to be performed atomically. That is very different from undefined behavior. So, which is right? Consider the program below, for example:

```
__device__ int X = 1;

__device__ void A() {
  X = 2;
}

__device__ void B() {
  while (X != 2) {}
}
```

If threads A and B are launched at the same time, is B guaranteed to halt? If reading from the same memory is UB, then the answer would be no, as `X` could be "corrupted" and never be read properly; thus, we would need to use `atomicExch(&X,2)` and `atomicAdd(&X,0)` instead. But it is not clear to me if that is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA does not have `atomicRead` because of a combination of several factors:

1. You would only need an "atomic read" if you were reading something not accessed in a single physical memory read operation (in which case a write might change a second part after we have read the first part).
2. On NVIDIA GPUs, data of a given size can only be stored in addresses being a multiple of this size, i.e. data is size-aligned.
3. Physical memory reads are larger than the largest data type a thread can read.

(2.)+(3.) mean that a single read only ever requires data obtained by a single physical memory operation. This + (1.) means that all individual reads are atomic.

So, no need for `atomicRead`.

---

PS - About the article you linked to: It regards memory fencing for threads in a block, so that they see the results of the same sequence of memory operations. Even if all these operations were atomic - that would still not have helped us, because atomicity does not regard multiple operations on different data.